# Phonegap vertical scrolling within page issues

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, cordova

I'm building a phonegap(cordova) application and it is working great for android, but there is some scrolling issue with iOS build i-e i cannot scroll pages from anywhere on the screen except the middle-right and middle-left of the screen and that area is very less, i want to scroll by swiping anywhere on the screen just like it works in Android.

Anyone else faces the same issue, share your knowledge and experience.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle of your html and css code?

Answer (score 1):

Although without a code sample it is difficult to advice.. I had similar experiences in ios phonegap development and you need to be sure that the css `overflow` attribute is correctly setup for all elements.

One major 'trick' that you need is to add

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

To the container you like to scroll.
See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling) page for info about the css property.

Comment: your solution did a little trick, but i have this 'header.getClientRects()[0].height') in my code when it executes my application scrolls perfectally, but when it does not it gives ""TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'header.getClientRects()[0].height') "" and application starts scrolling horizontally

Comment: @Tahir on what element do you call this function? (What is header?) maybe post your complete code?